# Resharper attribute to disable "never assigned" but not "never used" warnings

Tags: c#, resharper, custom-attributes

I have a factory that instantiates objects and fill in fields that are marked with a custom attribute.  Resharper puts a green underline under those fields complaining that "Field 'Example' is never assigned". To suppress the warning I can add the `MeansImplicitUseAttribute` to my custom attribute. The problem is that attribute also suppresses the "Field 'Example' is never **used**" warning, which is helpful to me so I'd like to preserve it.

Can I mark my attribute such that I don't get "never assigned" warnings but I still get the "never used" ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, there are parameters to the MeansImplicitUse attribute that specify the type of use, so I actually want to add `[MeansImplicitUse(ImplicitUseKindFlags.Assign)]` to my attribute definition. Simple!